# AJAX call is getting stopped after page refresh

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

I am a newbie in javascript. I have a AJAX call in a button click to process a back-end function and get a response once the function is done but when I do refresh the page in between, my AJAX stopped and I am not receiving any response from backed.

Comment: Uhm, yeah, that’s how things work … When you reload the page, the browser cancels all pending or running requests - it assumes they are not going to be needed any more, because after all, you just explicitly said, “Hey, I want this page reloaded in its initial state.” So - simply don’t do that then …?

Comment: But I need to get the progress from the backend process every 2 seconds. Kindly giude me is there any other way

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by refreshing?

Comment: Send a new ajax request every 2 seconds basically. You could look into sockets or other server push options, but that will be alot more complex to set up. Keep in mind that due to latency and timings, 2 seconds won't mean your ajax call always resolves in 2 seconds. Any way to increase the required rate of polling above 2 seconds?

Comment: Actually, I need to run a process through nodejs which will take time to finish till then i dont want the user to wait, all I need to show the progress of that in my UI. So I used AJAX call to keep on read the progress and update in UI. But when this is happening, if I refresh the page in between, my AJAX stopped so I am not getting the progress in UI

Comment: If you want to avoid that, then you’ll have to implement it in a way that your page, when freshly loaded, always automatically makes an AJAX request to try and figure out if there still is any running background process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sessionStorage to keep a track of which process is running and when the page refresh you can get the data from that and start the Ajax request again if the process is not completed yet.